# How can I set the value of a slider in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a jQuery slider on my page having min -100 and max 100 and startValue 0. I want to provide a reset button which will reset the slider value to 0.

I am not able to find any setter function to do that, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

As i can see you can get or set the value of the slider:

```
$("#slider).slider('value', 0);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider/slider#.22value.22value

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the trick?

```
$("#slider").slider("value",0);
```